# XSD Visualization?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been working with a lot of semi-complicated XSD's lately and am wondering:  What are some of the better tools for working with XML schema?  Are there any graphical tools?

Standalone or Eclipse-based are ideal as we aren't a .net shop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find the [Eclipse standard XSD editor](http://www.eclipse.org/xsd) to be OK. See some screenshots [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_XSD_Editor). You can install it from the standard update site.

Answer (score 6):

I have been hunting for tools to visualise XSD files for a long while now. and as already stated. my top two are

- [Altova XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/)

  - Best features and great look and feel. prohibitively expensive for the small user.
- [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/)

  - Really good alternative to Altova, does things a little differently, but its worth finding out the methods in LiquidXML

Outside of those two, I personally struggle to find tools which can present all the information visually (especially long XSD Files). this includes listing the enumeration values of elements.

If you just need a quick method to view XSD files visually, I quite like these two viewing tools.

- [XSD Diagram](http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram) - EXE file download
- [XML Grid](http://xmlgrid.net/) - Online XSD viewer

Answer (score 3):

Try:

- [Oxygen XML Schema Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_schema_editor.html)
- [Liquid Technologies' XML / XSD Editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/)

There are plenty others, too - but I prefer one of those two.

Marc

Comment: Wow. Neither of those are cheap. Have you been an active user of both of these products?

Comment: There's no community edition anymore, superseded by Starter version

Answer (score 3):

We use [Liquid Xml Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Free-Xsd-Editor.aspx), it make life so much easier, with diagrams you can actually understand and edit directly. We used the free version for ages, and have now managed to get the boss to pay for the full version.

[image]
<sub>(source: [liquid-technologies.com](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Images/ScreenShots/XmlStudio/InlineEdit_322x202.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I love this product!
it has such a good tutorial on their website.
http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_01.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth it: [Altova XMLSPY](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/)

Comment: If you're doing heavy XML development, it's worth every penny.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Eclipse, or you already use Netbeans, there is an XSD Editing plugin that Geertjan describes how to install on his blog: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/xml_schema_editor_in_netbeans

I may be mistaken, but I think this XSD Editor used to be bundled with the IDE, and I feel like it still should be.  Either way, it works really well, especially on top of the Netbeans platform.